# Rotate Div using J2Html

Tags: java, j2html

By using `J2Html` in `JAVA` and I need to rotate div (90deg) and it needs to be shown in Binary representation of HTML (`Binary Value`).

This is example of what I've tried so far:

```
ContainerTag test = TagCreator.div().withStyle("transform: rotate(90deg);transform-origin: right top 0;float: right;").withText("Some test");
```

but it's not working (same thing in `.html` file is working as expected)

Any other ideas?